# How to write sql result into csv file

Tags: perl, sql-server-2008

I'm having two tables like A and B. Table A having the Columns Name. Table B having the Columns Company Name.

This is my code:

```
$query1 = "SELECT Name FROM A"; 
$query2 = "SELECT Company Name FROM B"; 

$statement1 = $connection->prepare($query1);    
$statement2 = $connection->prepare($query2);

$statement1->execute();
$statement2>execute();

while ( ($name) = $statement->fetchrow_array) {
    push (@Name, $name);    
} 
while ( ($companyname) = $statement->fetchrow_array) {
    push (@companyName, $companyname);  
}

open (FH, ">>Output.csv") or die "$!";
```

I need to write the data in the csv file like this

```
Name   CompanyName

xxx     yyyy

xxx     yyyy

xxx     yyyy

xxx     yyyy

xxx     yyyy
```

Comment: You should always `use strict` and `use warnings`, and declare your variables with `my`. It's not clear what your question is. Is there an error message?

Comment: Okay hereafter i'll use strict and warning.I need to write the data into csv file.

Comment: Please post the files in question, or at least test files which replicate your environment. Its easier to answer when we have some data to play around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a `JOIN` in your SQL query. You don't need to do two `SELECT` statements.

```
'SELECT a.Name, b.CompanyName FROM A a JOIN B b ON a.MailId = b.MailId'
```

---

Here's a complete example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("put:dsn:here");
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT a.Name, b.CompanyName FROM A a JOIN B b ON a.MailId = b.MailId');

open my $fh, '>>', 'Output.csv' or die "Could not open file Output.csv: $!";
print $fh qq{Name\tCompanyName\n};

$sth->execute;
while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
  print $fh qq{$res->{'Name'}\t$res->{'CompanyName'}\n};
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: I'm having two queries. First query result should be write in the one column. second query result should be write in the next column

Comment: !Stefan Edwards: are you sure? Are you certain the names and company names are listed in a consistent order? Usually you're not and you do a join to match them up.